# file post/upload through curl in php

Tags: php, curl

This is my curl initiation code:

```
  $target="url/curlUploadHandler.php";
  $args = new CURLFile('down.png', 'image/png','test'); //file to post
  $postFields = array('file' => $args);
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $target);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
  $r = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  print_r($r); // to get response from the page
```

And this is to check whether given file is getting posted or not:

**curlUploadHandler.php**

```
       if($_REQUEST){
               var_dump($_REQUEST);
          }
```

**or**

```
if( $_FILES ) {
       var_dump($_FILES );}
```

I am testing this code on local. Posting fields like string or integer is working fine but posting an image or any other file is not giving me any output. Am I missing some options in `cURL` or doing something wrong? I have checked the docs already [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php). Help me out please.

And please comment before downvoting :/ if you have to :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$target must be "http://[HOST]/url/curlUploadHandler.php"

**Check for errors**

```
if( $errno = curl_errno($curl) ) { 
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno); 
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}"; 
}
```

and

- put in your code echo getcwd(); to check the full path
- check with is_readable the image
- check permisions of image

Comment: I Know that. Everything is fine. I need to know how to post files through **cURL**. That _url_ word is representing my whole url

Comment: what version of php do you have ?

Comment: I am using php 5.5.12 @CatalinB

Comment: image is in the same directory ?  check for errors  if($errno = curl_errno($curl)) {
  $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
  echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
 }

Comment: Yes image is in the same directory. Okay let me use your error code. I will get back to you after checking that.

Comment: **cURL error (26): Failed to open/read local data from file/application**   I am getting this error message

Comment: put the absolute path of image

Comment: Already did that not working. I am getting the same error message

Comment: 1) put in your code echo getcwd(); to check the full path; 2) check with is_readable the image; 3) check permisions of image

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
$target="url/curlUploadHandler.php";  
$file_name_with_full_path = realpath('down.png');
$post = array('extra_info' => 'test','file_contents'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
print_r($result);
```

You can also refer for better understanding : http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/

Comment: using @  _filename_  is deprecated. I am using php 5.5.12

Comment: @Dherya: wait let i check it first. just because i use old version of PHP.

Comment: Yes u r right. in PHP 5.5+ it is depricated : but now we should use wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload but if you still want to use this deprecated approach then you need to set curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);

Comment: no i don't want to use deprecated approach @Jignesh M. Mehta

Comment: and still setting `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);` is giving me error when i used your approach

Comment: @Dherya : No problem. just find new solution and give you a better answer ok.

Comment: @Dherya: Have you got any other solution?